# Why is the degree of a Weil divisor meaningless?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a irreducible smooth proper scheme over a field $k$.

The group of Weil divisors is the free abelian group on the set of prime divisors (irreducible closed subschemes of codimension 1).

Thus, any Weil divisor $D$ can be written as a finite sum $D = \sum_i n_i[Y_i]$ where $Y_i$ is prime divisor.

Let $baddegree(D) := \sum_i n_i$. I want to understand why baddegree is not meaningful.

Here are some explicit questions:

(1). Suppose $k$ is algebraically closed. What is the simplest explicit example of $X$ and a function $f$ on $X$ with $baddegree(div(f)) \ne 0$ (where $div(f)$ is as defined in Hartshorne)

(2). Intuitively, why do such functions as in (1) exist?

(3). If $k$ is not algebraically closed, baddegree is already bad, even for curves. For example on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ with coordinate $t$, $baddegree(div(t^2+1)) = -1$. Is there some sense in which this badness is related to the badness that appears for higher dimensional varieties?

Comment: For $(1)$ you can take $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $f([x:y:z])=\frac{xy}{x^2-yz}$. It vanishes along the line $x=0$ (call it $L_1$), along $y=0$ (call it $L_2$) and has a pole along the irreducible conic $x^2-yz=0$ (call it $C$). So the divisor of $f$ is $[L_1]+[L_2]-[C]$ of "baddegree" 1. The point is that $C$ should be considered as a degree 2 divisor even if it is irreducible. The situation is a bit different from $(3)$ where you had an irreducible divisor which is not geometrically irreducible, but similar because the "unique zero" of $t^2+1$ and of $x^2-yz$ is defined by an equation of degree >1